# sharing a specific jquery mobile #page on using social network buttons

Tags: jquery, facebook, mobile, share

How to you share a specific jquery #page on using social network buttons.

I'm making a Jquery mobile website for someone who makes dresses.  Each dress will have it's own page id with a photo and description.  I would like to add share buttons for facebook, Google+ and Twitter under each dress so people can share that specific dress with friends etc. 
When I try using the URL www.website.co.uk/index.html#dress1 the '#dress1' always gets stripped when posted on facebook.  Thanks for any help you can offer on this.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It's usually used within an HTML document since it does not locate a unique resource by itself.

For links meant to be shared, it's better to build URLs using parameters or directory-like structures (e.g. www.website.co.uk/index.html/dress/1)